# How to change other records based on single records in the query not by updating the table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 fiscal_Quarter(FQ) values for each country and I want to replace my 1st and 2nd FQ denominator values with 3rd FQ Denominator value. Below is the sample data which I want to achieve.
Note: I am trying to achieve this in my query result not by update the table data.

This is how my data looks like:

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsamt.jpg)

This is what I am trying to achieve.

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjKyh.jpg)

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual input / expected output as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the table by joining itself.

```
UPDATE a
SET a.Denominator = b.Denominator
FROM tableName a
    INNER JOIN tableName b
        ON a.Country = b.Country
            AND b.FQ = 'FQ3'
```

Here's a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8d74b/1).

Based on your comment, you don't need to update the query but instead show `FQ3` Denominator to all `FQ`.

```
SELECT a.country, a.fq, a.numerator, b.denominator
FROM TableName a
        INNER JOIN tableName b
            ON a.Country = b.Country
                AND b.fq = 'fq3'
```

Here's a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/218a6/1).

Answer (score 0):

what if you use of *window function* ?

```
 SELECT *, 
        max(denominator) over (order by country)  denominator1
 FROM table
```

Other option is to use of *correlated sub-query*

```
SELECT t.country, t.fq, t.numerATOR, 
          (SELECT TOP 1 denominator FROM table WHERE country = t.country ORDER BY fq DESC) 
FROM table t
```